# A sequence of three letter words/abbreviations

Tags: sequence, crossword-clues, word-ladder

I have ten three letter words/abbreviations in a sequence, numbered 0-9, each of which differ by precisely one letter from their previous and next words.  Here are clues for each of the words:

> 0. The Fantastic 4 break this
> 1. Superior to 5 for information transfer... in closed areas
> 2. What the Fantastic 4 is definitely not
> 3. Incredibly cold... and quite dangerous
> 4. Eats 3... in a former state
> 5. See 1.
> 6. Pair with 9 to comply with a treaty
> 7. Impossible
> 8. Visit this often if you like schadenfreude
> 9. See 6

What are the ten words?

Here's a hint:

> "Fantastic 4" should really be "Fantastic Mr. 4"

More hints: an additional set of clues

> 0. see 6
> 1. Add a ringing noise, and this happens at 2 all the time
> 2. Third busiest in the world... but perhaps not under current conditions
> 3. The closest we have to 7 uses this
> 4. "Can't let you do that"
> 5. One letter away from 2
> 6. 1791: A landmark U.S. 0 concerns this
> 7. see 3
> 8. One letter from 6
> 9. "There are many like it, but this one is mine"

Comment: Good puzzle +1, but are these really cryptic clues? Or are they simply crossword-type clues?

Comment: just for clarification, by "differ by precisely one letter" you mean that "ICE" would match "ACE", but not "INC", because the position of the other letters must be preserved, right?

Comment: @Lukas Rotter Yes, that's correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the answers are:

> 0 LAW (the Fantastic Four break it)
>  1 LAN (better than FAX(5) for short-range data transfer; LAN/DING happens at LAX(2))
>  2 LAX (the Fantastic Four are not; it is a busy airport)
>  3 LOX (used for rocket propulsion; cf. FTL(7))
>  4 FOX (eats salmon, the precursor of LOX(3), if it can get it, though I didn't think that was particularly a thing foxes were noted for; "Fantastic Mr. Fox"; "Can't let you do that" seems to be a reference to a game called Star Fox)
>  5 FAX (not so good as a LAN(1) for data transfer; one letter away from LAX(2))
>  6 FAL (a kind of rifle, I ?think?; the US law is the Bill of Rights, more specifically the Second Amendment, though it doesn't concern this kind of rifle *in particular*)
>  7 FTL (faster-than-light travel is impossible)
>  8 FML (website providing much schadenfreude; one letter from FAL(6))
>  9 FMJ (FMJ bullets, unlike some other sorts, comply with the Hague Convention; the Rifleman's Creed occurs in the movie *Full Metal Jacket*)